# Method not found, cucumber tests

Tags: java, cucumber

Hey fellow hackermann :)

I have a problem with my cucumber Tests:

I would like to take screenshots during my testing and embed the screenshot into my Scenario

the code I am using for this is:

```
private void makeSnapshot (String name){
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        this.scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png",name);
        //return screenshot;
    }
```

My pom file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumCucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

The error message:

[image]

I guess I am using a wrong dependency, but I don't know which is wrong as I am fairly new to the whole subject

The method is NOT depricated (already checked)

Has anyone any idea how to fix this, any help is awesome

Thank you in advance

Comment: parameters wrong?   ( i am not a java programmer)

Comment: when I check the method, it is defined in the Scenario class like so:

```
public void embed(byte[] data, String mediaType, String name) {
        this.delegate.embed(data, mediaType, name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies are inconsistent. You are including different incompatible versions of cucumber dependencies as well as transitive dependencies.

You should start from scratch with the https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/ and only add those dependencies you need.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you're using Cucumber-Core `6.2.1`, you should be using `attach` method which has the same signature. Refer [TestCaseState#attach](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/6.2.1/io/cucumber/core/backend/TestCaseState.html)

Comment: thanks man, but my dependencies were wrong
in the end I used the method attach, but it didn'T work with Cucumber-Core 6.2.1
only after I followed M.P. Korstanje advice it worked, I can't accept both answers but thank you very much ;)